# Fourier series, can i get matlab to print the answer from each of theses loop?

Tags: matlab, fft

Matlab, can I get matlab to print the answer from each of these loops on 3 separate lines?
I keep getting it to graph correctly but it seems to only print the last fprintf or is printing the 3 totals together? 
Thanks in advance
P.S Sorry about this question as I know it's a pretty straight forward problem but I'm very new to matlab!!

```
clc;

a= input('\n\nEnter a value for a: ');
b= input('\n\nEnter a value for b: ');
L= input('\n\nEnter a value for L: ');

a0 = (a+b)/2; %average value of the function over one complete cycle

t = 0:0.1:6*L;

fprintf('ft = %f',a0)
f=a0;



for k=1:2:20; %loop 10 times to give first 10 terms of the series

bk = ((b-a)*2)/(k*pi); %value for bk
f=f+bk*sin(k*pi*t/L);

fprintf(' + %fsin%ft',bk,(k*pi/L))

end
subplot(2,3,1);
plot(t,f,'g');

title('Fourier Series');

ylabel('Amplitude');
xlabel('Time');
grid on;


for k=1:2:50; %loop 25 times to give first 25 terms of the series

bk = ((b-a)*2)/(k*pi); %value for bk
f=f+bk*sin(k*pi*t/L);

%fprintf(' + %fsin%ft',bk,(k*pi/L))

end
subplot(2,3,2);
plot(t,f, 'r');
title('Fourier Series');

ylabel('Amplitude');
xlabel('Time');
grid on;


for k=1:2:100; %loop 50 times to give first 50 terms of the series

bk = ((b-a)*2)/(k*pi); %value for bk
f=f+bk*sin(k*pi*t/L);

%fprintf(' + %fsin%ft',bk,(k*pi/L))

end
subplot(2,3,4);
plot(t,f, 'b')
title('Fourier Series');

ylabel('Amplitude');
xlabel('Time');
grid on;
```

Answer (score -1):

add `\n` into the fprintf statement, like this:

`fprintf(' + %f sin %ft\n',bk,(k*pi/L))`